# ASP/SQL/Paging - Get current page number

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, paging

**I answered my own question, sorry!**

I started with this:

```
If Request("currentPage") <> "" AND isNumeric(Request("currentPage")) Then
    currentPage = Request("currentPage")
Else
    currentPage = 1
End If
```

And then on my paging links, I added:

```
.asp?currentPage="&currentPage+1&"
```

### ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have upgraded my search script to use LIMIT paging.

I am simply trying to work out what the current page is, based on the 'offset' value but I'm having some amateur troubles.

This is what I have:

```
currentPage = pageRange / rpp

' page range is the offset value for the LIMIT clause, for example 0, 20, 40...
' rpp is results per page value, for example 20...

If cInt(currentPage) <= 0 Then
    currentPage = 1
End If
```

But page 1 and 2 both show "page 1", page 3 shows "page 2", page 4 shows "page 3" and so on. Obviously there is something wrong with this calculation but I cannot see it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be better to keep track on page num and evaluate offset from it, than tracking offset?  Or at least evaluate currentPage as cInt(pageRange / rpp)+1

Comment: Sorry skazska, I answered my own question. I edit my question to show you how I solved it